# Where can I find code examples or documentation showing how to develop worklight Apps with off-line capability

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am started to develop my first worklight App Proof of Concept. There are some good examples on developer works of on-line apps but nothing that takes data off-line in a synchronising fashion. Id there anything like the "Kitchen Sink" demo in the Titanium suite ?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps what you should be looking at is the JSONStore feature, which provides sync functionality. Basically, once your app goes back online and is connected to the Worklight Server, use JSONStore's sync ability to fetch/send data.

- [Worklight adapter integration for JSONStore](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_jsonstore_wl_adapter_integration.html)

More reading materials:

- [JSONStore – The client-side JSON-based database overview](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/05_08_JSONStore_-_The_client_side_JSON_based_database_overview.pdf)
- [JSONStore – Common JSONStore Usage](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/05_09_JSONStore_-_Common_JSONStore_Usage.pdf) ([sample project](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/JSONStoreAPIBasicsProject.zip))